# How to handle the ambiguity between default constructor and overloaded constructor?

Tags: c++

The line A b(3) produces ambiguity as it could invoke any of the two possible constructors. Either the single argument parametrized constructor or the two-argument parametrized constructor with default argument. How do i solve this?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
    int a,b;
    A()
    {
        a=5;
        b=6;
    }
    A(int a1)
    {
        a=a1;
        b=54;
    }
    A(int a1,int b2=8)
    {
        a=a1;
        b=b2;
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout<<"a="<<a<<" b="<<b<<endl;
    }
};    
int main()
{
    A a(3); // I want A(int a1,int b2=8) to get executed
    A b(3); // I want A(int a1) to get executed
    a.show();
    b.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avoid such thing to begin with, you have two constructor calls that would look identical but produce different objects.

Comment: In one, you're assigning `b` 54 if there's no argument, and in the other you're assigning it 8 in the exact same circumstances. What's with that? I think this is a case of the XY problem. If there's some reason you want this behaviour, there's a higher level problem.

Comment: is there no way to solve this ambiguity so it invokes the constructor we want it to?

Comment: And how is the compiler supposed to know which constructor you want it to call?

Comment: my question exactly! is there any operator, or syntax which is to be explicitly used, so the compiler knows that OK, the user wants this constructor

Comment: But why would you want that? Please show us what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: i was just trying to find if either has a greater priority, when invoked with a single argument, but the compiler showed that it was an ambiguity, so i just want to know, if it is ever possible to make a single argument object run the above code?

Comment: No, that's the point. There can't be any ambiguities because there is no priority system there.

Comment: You have written two different ways of expressing the exact same constructor call, except with different behaviors.  First you need to choose the behavior you want.  Specifically, what value should `b` take when the constructor is called with one argument?  Then pick the representation you like better and delete the other.  That's how you assign the "priority".

Comment: what i actually want is that: different objects (with single arguments) run the different constructors, as per the need! is there any way, any explicit syntax of making this possible?

Comment: @Ashwyn, could you give a better example in your post of what you want?

Comment: Ok, from what I see, you're randomly choosing which constructor you want. If you want the constructor to be chosen based on the value of `a`, have one and perform that check inside. Right now there's no apparent logic behind the choice.

Comment: i dont want it based on the value of the parameters, suppose at different instances in the program, i want different objects (though with same argument) to invoke different constructors!

Comment: But how are you choosing which one you want it to execute? As Luchian Grigore poses, "If you don't know what you want from the code, how can you expect the compiler to?" You need some way of choosing which one you want.

Comment: If you want the _programmer_ to be able to decide which he wants to use, you want to use the [named constructor idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.8)

Comment: i think i am wasting your time over unnecessary and trivial discussions, all i want to know is, is it, at all, possible to invoke different constructors for different objects, as in the above code, by using any **keywords** which need to be **explicitly used**!

Comment: @Ashwyn, see there you go. **That** is the logic behind the choice. The programmer is choosing which one via the explicit keywords. Mooing Duck's solution is appropriate then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, answer this:

When you write `A a(4)`, do you want `a.b.` to be:

Option a) **54**

```
class A
{
    public:
    int a,b;
    A()
    {
        a=5;
        b=6;
    }
    A(int a1,int b2 = 54)
    {
        a=a1;
        b=b2;
    }
};
```

Option b) **8**

```
class A
{
    public:
    int a,b;
    A()
    {
        a=5;
        b=6;
    }
    A(int a1,int b2 = 8)
    {
        a=a1;
        b=b2;
    }
};
```

The error is there for a reason. **If you don't know what you want from the code, how can you expect the compiler to?**

EDIT: After your edit - impossible. Not with that exact code.

Comment: This is the only real solution to this question. The logic behind this is very flawed. There's two different behaviours stemming from the same code.

Answer (score 1):

what you're asking for from the compiler has the ambiguity.

```
A(int a1)
{
    a=a1;
    b=54;
}
```

and

```
A(int a1,int b2=8)
{
    a=a1;
    b=b2;
}
```

are the same when your class gets created by only one parameter. write-down your expectation from the class in english language for yourself first. then, convert it to c++ code. Example: "If my class A is created with only one parameter, than make my variable a equal to that parameter and let my variable b be 54. If it's created by two params than give the first one to a, and the second one to b" and your code for this expression is:

```
A(int a1,int b2=54)
{
    a=a1;
    b=b2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `A(int a1)` function and instead of `A b(3)` call `A b(3, 54)`

Answer (score 0):

In your example there's no way for the compiler to tell whether you mean the second or third constructor when it is invoked with only a single argument.

Typically if you need to add a new constructor with additional default arguments you would make the defaults result in the same behavior as the earlier constructor and get rid of the earlier version, e.g. in this case the default for b2 would have to be 54. Alternatively don't give the new constructor a default argument and just require the caller to pass it explicitly.

I suppose another option would be to have multiple derived classes with default constructors that pass different arguments to the base class constructor.

```
class A
{
public:
    int a, b;
    A() { a = 5; b = 6; }
    A(int a1) { a = a1; b = 54; }
    A(int a1, int b1) { a = a1; b = b1; }
    ...
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B(int a1): A(a1, 8) { }
};
```

Code that wants A::b initialized with 8 instead of 54 create a B instead. That isn't a good option in many situations though.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the default =8 in the constructor and it fixes it.  You can specify the 54 in the implementation of the constructor, but not a parameter.  Otherwise it will confuse it with the other constructor without that =8 parameter.